# how to deploy MVVM app?

Tags: deployment, dll, mvvm

So i have created an app using the MVVM pattern. I'm ready to give this to a couple friends to test out for me.  So i make a folder and copy over my files
- MyApp.exe
- MyApp.ViewModel.dll
- MyApp.Model.dll
- MyApp.Common.dll
- config.xml

I sent it out and now its time to fix bugs and add features.  The only files that changed were
- MyApp.exe
- MyApp.ViewModel.dll
- MyApp.Model.dll

What is the best way to deploy these changes?  I can see people just copying over the exe file and the program may run if the changes to the model or viewmodel were not huge.. I could also see this becoming a nightmare to figure out if if everyone is using the correct dll files.  What is best practice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use ClickOnce to deploy the app to a regular http server. Once you make changes they'll be updated with the latest version of your app. It's pretty easy.

http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2009/02/18/clickonce-getting-started-sample/

Answer (score 0):

Randolf's suggestion is indeed the best option.
however, if you don't have access to an http server, you might want to use [versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to differentiate between releases.
that way you and your testers can easily see what version they're using (you can even display the assembly version info in the UI for convenience).